# Creating a new variable by comparing variable values across rows in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, case

I have a dataset with 4 variables. They are `id`, `last_name`, `first_name`, and `email`. Lets say similar ids, last names and first names can be repeated across multiple rows and the way to find out if its the same or different person is by comparing emails. Lets consider the following code and dataset:

```
id <- c("12-A", "12-A", "12-A", "12-A")

last_name <- c("Mike", "Mike", "Mike", "Mike")

first_name <- c("Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom")

email <- c("tom@yahoo.com", "tom@yahoo.com", "tom@yahoo.com", "tommike@yahoo.com")

ds <- data.frame(id, last_name, first_name, email)
```

The following is the  output:

```
    id  last_name   first_name  email
                
1   12-A    Mike    Tom         tom@yahoo.com
2   12-A    Mike    Tom         tom@yahoo.com
3   12-A    Mike    Tom         tom@yahoo.com
4   12-A    Mike    Tom         tommike@yahoo.com
```

Now I want to create an another variable (identity) that input value `Yes` if given the same id, last_name, first_name, emails are the same, if the email is different as in row # 4, I want the input values to say "No". How can I do that especially using `dplyr::mutate` with `case_when`

Thanks

Comment: The trickiest part of understanding this question for me is why rows 1-3 are "Yes" and 4 is "No". What conditions decide which is the "correct" email address to test for?

Comment: @AndyBaxter does it matter. This is a coding question.  Also this is a make-up data. The data I am using have unique emails assigned by a domain that will assign you only one email (domain will be the same) if you are one person. Like at the company you work or the University you go to etc.

Comment: Can row 1-3 be "No" and row 4 be "Yes"?  Or, if an email is counted more than 1 time, is "Yes", else is "No"?

Answer (score 1):

How about if you just concatenate all the variables that you want to constitute an ID and then coerce it to a factor? Would this be ok?

```
ds$identity <- paste(ds$id, ds$last_name, ds$first_name, ds$email, sep = "-")
ds$identity <- as.numeric(as.factor(ds$identity))
ds

    id last_name first_name             email identity
1 12-A      Mike        Tom     tom@yahoo.com        1
2 12-A      Mike        Tom     tom@yahoo.com        1
3 12-A      Mike        Tom     tom@yahoo.com        1
4 12-A      Mike        Tom tommike@yahoo.com        2
```

Comment: Thank you @Roman Lustrik! This is good. Just want to explore different ways of doing this.